# Unable to load beans from Application Context in junit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I'm trying to implement a group of tests for my app. In this case, I have some mybatis mappers whose beans are defined in my applicationContext.xml. For example:

```
<bean id="usersMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.myapp.dao.UserMapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I've been looking for hours how to implement junit tests properly because some internet posts are deprecated or not up to date. This is my junit class actually:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:*applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class GroupTest {


    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void testCreateGroup() throws SQLException {
        UserMapper um = (UserMapper)context.getBean("usersMapper");  
    }
}
```

There are no errors during the startup. When I try to get the bean usersMapper returns an exception (There is no bean definition..) Maybe, is not loading the properly applicationContext?

I also tried Mockito with no success. I've read it does cool things, but is it capable of loading the context as well as Spring? When I call the getUsers method from UserMapper, it returns null. This is my implementation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:*applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class GroupTest {


    @Mock
    private UserMapper userMapper;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testCreateGroup() throws SQLException {
        userMapper.getUsers(); 
    }
}
```

For the record... my applicationContext.xml is placed in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
Hope you can guide me the right way. Thank you

Edit1: applicationContext.xml and context.xml added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/adminDB"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="usersMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="es.unican.meteo.dao.UserMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

It seems that Peter Hart solution loads the applicationContext.xml but a new problem appears. I need to use a jndi Resource in my app (reference included in applicationContext.xml). Is this no possible in test environment?
The exception shows the following:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

This is my context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/adminDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
             maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" username="***" password="***"
             driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
             url="jdbc:***"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: If you want to use a jndi resource during your tests, include a jndi.properties file in the classpath and include context information in this file. e.g., `java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099`. The values of the properties will change based on the application server the datasource is in. You can also set these as system properties. Alternatively, you can use a direct connection to the database instead of a datasource.

Comment: But I have a question. If the datasource definition is still there with its property jndiName... How do I link the file that you propose with the datasource? I think you are proposing something similar that jdbc.properties where you read these properties in the datasource of the applicationContext. And another question... How can I difference the applicationContext between Test envionment and deployment ? Maybe I need to have two?

Comment: When you specify a datasource with a jndi name, spring internally will try to create an Initial Context to look up the jndi resource. For creating an Initial Context, the properties abve are required as they tell the application where the jndi resource is registered. These properties can be specified as System properties (e.g. -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory) or can be put in the jndi.properties file located in the classpath.

Comment: As for the applicationContext, you can have a separate file for test. You have to make sure the test context file is read before by specifying the test context folder before the application(src) one in the classpath. In eclipse, you can do this using the 'Order and Export' tab in 'Project properties>Java Build Path'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've requested a classpath resource, and `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` is probably not on the classpath (it usually wouldn't be).

You could try moving the applicationContext.xml to somewhere on the classpath. I'm guessing that you are using maven, in which case,  this would usually either be `src/main/resources`, or `src/test/resources` (if this is specific to a particular test, rather than a 'real' application context file). I would also fix your `@ContextConfiguration` as @ohiocowboy suggests (assuming you put it directly in that directory, as things will generally work better if you're explicit about the location).

If your application context absolutely needs to be in `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, you might try using `file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. If you run from the base directory of the project with `mvn test`, it should work, and it would probably work from the eclipse test runner also (no idea about Idea or NetBeans, but my guess is that it might work).

Comment: Hi Peter. Is it wrong to place applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF? It would be best practices to include it into src/main/resources? I edited my first post. It seems to work but I have problems loading the jndi resource.

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, per se. I'm not really qualified to speak on best practices for Spring, but for a web application it is not uncommon to see the applicationContext.xml somewhere under WEB-INF, although I've rarely seen it directly under WEB-INF. The JNDI issue I'm not sure how to fix - in our environments, we usually put the datasource definition in a separate imported file, and pull in a different (embedded database datasource) for our test code. Did you try Priyesh's suggestion above?

Answer (score 0):

Your application context is not being loaded properly. The locations attribute of the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation should be `"classpath:main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"`, `"classpath:**/applicationContext.xml"` or `"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"`. When you run the test, the application is not deployed, hence WEB-INF will not be in the classpath(unless you have added it to the test classpath yourself).

When using a mock object, you need to provide mock implementations for the methods that are going to be called. The `getUsers()` method is returning null because you have not set the desired result. You can check the mockito website for examples at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html.

Comment: Hi @Priyesh. Neither your first solution nor the second one works for me. The first one throws "class path resource [main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist" and the second one, starts but when I try to execute context.getBean("usersMapper"); .. "No bean named 'usersMapper' is defined"

Comment: Have you checked if there is any other applicationContext.xml in the classpath?

Comment: There might be a applicationContext.xml in one of the libraries you use. That is probably the one being loaded. How are you running the tests? From an IDE or maven/ant?

Comment: I've checked. I'm running the test from Eclipse and my intention is to  deploy the war running the test through Maven too.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext.xml"})
```

UPDATE
Actually that doesn't work either because. The applicationContext.xml isn't on the classpath. It needs to be moved into the WEB-INF/classes directory.

Comment: A short text on how this helps the OP would be helpful.

Comment: @Peter hart answer is a more complete answer to the question